# Hide sheets VBA - Excel bug?

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently doing a VBA code that needs to hide some sheets when the Excel file is closed and almost everything is working fine expects when I do the following steps:

1. make some change/insert data in the sheets
2. click the save button
3. make another change (that I do not want to save)
4. click to close the file and click not to save it

The problem is that I hide the sheets but since I do not save the file (because i do not want to save the changes made at step 3) the sheets are not hidden when I reopen the file. I cannot do this with the Workbook_open method because it is not allowed (at my project).

To do this I am rewriting the beforeclose method, as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim ireply As Integer

    If Not Me.Saved Then
        Msg = "Do you want to save the file?"
        ireply = MsgBox(Msg, vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)

        Select Case ireply
            Case vbYes
                Call hidesheets
                Me.Save

            Case vbNo
                Me.Saved = True
                Application.Quit

            Case vbCancel
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
          End Select

          Else
            Call hidesheets
            Me.Save

    End If
End Sub

Sub hidesheets()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Brands").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Models").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

My questions is, it is possible just to save the hidden sheets configurations/settings without saving the information/data changed/inserted by the user?

PS: when I save the file and make any change the code works fine, i.e. hides the sheets.

Thank you all in advance
Regards

Comment: The only way I see it possible is by closing, reopening in the background, hiding the sheets, saving, and reclosing. Or hide the sheets in the BeforeSave code.

Comment: The real question is,  WHY ARE YOU MAKING A CHANGE THAT YOU DONT WANT TO SAVE??

Comment: The `Workbook_BeforeSave` event is unreliable. It depends on how a user closes a file (if the event actually fires). For example: if the Excel application is closed (without closing the Excel file within first) and this Excel instance is the only one open then it can happen that the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event is not called upon.

Comment: @StevenMartin, no reason to shout. It's a common situation to try to deal with. Here's a link you might enjoy: http://www.xl-central.com/force-users-to-enable-macros-in-a-workbook.html

Comment: maybe you should read his question again -  he clearly said step 2 was to save it......  and then went on to make a change and not save it. It defies logic

Comment: Thank you for the replies, @StevenMartin of course I'm anticipating something that might happen Of course if you read that as it is It not makes sense but it is something that can happen in the real world with real user (we all have done that).

Comment: @DougGlancy I have seen the page that you sent but I cannot see in the code where it is checked if the macros are or not enabled. There is any function/test to that.

Comment: It doesn't check, it just hides everything else but the warning sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Brands").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Models").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price").Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to do a save in order to that sheets be hidden when I reopen the workbook, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the other way around

1) Set your workbook having those four sheets as very hidden per default

set them as such and then save your workbook to have it assume its *default* configuration

2)  When you open it you make those sheets visible

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cars").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Brands").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Models").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price").Visible = True
End Sub
```

3) When you close it, you set those sheets back invisible

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    'Your code to be processed upon closing the sheet
    '...

    Call hidesheets '<--| hide your sheets
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @user3598756 but as mentioned previously i cannot use the workbook_open method